How to create a chart with custom graphics?

I need to create a chart looking like the image above, but I have no idea how. The data needs to be dynamic and it would great to also include some animation when the chart is loaded.
My tech stack includes:

Vue.js
Chart.js
TailwindCSS

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how achieve this? Would be really much appreciated :)
I've researched using Chart.js with Vue.js, but I'm having trouble finding resources that address the custom graphic (the yellow lines).

The question is too broad, and asking about the choice of libs is offtopic on SO. Basically a chart is either SVG or canvas. The former is the default choice. Then you animate SVG if necessary. It's unknown what kind of animation you talk about, probably it's possible with CSS anims, or you'll need a lib like GSAP or else. Notice that Chart.js is based on canvas rather than svg and may be not straightforward to customize graphics

You can use chart.js to implement a dynamic chart like the one in your image (although the precise specs are not stated), as you can use many other libraries. While chart.js has vue integrations, neither the js framework (vue) nor the css framework (tailwind) are relevant for creating the chart, although you need them for the other parts of your application. Please ask again, a SO-type question, i.e., one with a concrete technical problem, including what you have tried, as a runnable MRE, and we will be happy to answer.

To achieve a chart similar to the one in yours, here are a few key resources and steps you can check, maybe it will be helpful:

To create the curved line with a shaded area, check out the Chart.js documentation on line charts: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html
For the shaded area below the curve, you can use a gradient. Here's a useful video tutorial on how to set up a gradient fill in Chart.js:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-15uzfcd-I

Additionally, if you are open to exploring other libraries, I recommend checking eg: Apache ECharts, which I also use in my project. While I don’t have a chart like you but ECharts has a lot of great examples that might inspire you:
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/index.html#chart-type-line
